# Item scoreboard does not work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] ctl 2 {Item:{id:minecraft:torch,Count:1}}
```

Why does this command not work when I run it on 1.9?

Comment: Note:i was using 1.9 version

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to include all information, rather than leaving some of it buried in comments. I tried to put through an edit suggestion, but I'm on mobile, and the suggest edit functionality doesn't work very well at all.

Answer (score 1):

When testing for pre-existing data (such as with `/testfor`, `/scoreboard`, `/testforblock`), you must properly declare the data you're looking for as it's saved. The `Count` tag is saved as a byte, while you've declared it as an integer. You'll append the whole numerical value with a "b" to declare a byte:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] ctl 2 {Item:{id:"minecraft:torch",Count:1b}}
```